# Tenenbaum and Pollard, Ordinary Differential Equations, Exercise $1.3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Self-teaching ODE's, so I've decided to be thorough about it. First two problems were fine, but the answer given for problem $3$ does not align with mine. The problem is as follows:

> The following item appeared in a newspaper. "The expedition used the carbon-14 test to measure the amount of radioactivity still present in the organic material found in the ruins, thereby determining that a town existed there as long ago as $7000$ B.C." Using the half-life figure of $C^{14}$ as given in the text ($5600$ years), determine the approximate percentage of $C^{14}$ still present in the organic material at the time of the discovery.

*My work:* We have:

$$x=Ae^{-kt}$$

Where $x$ is the amount of $C^{14}$ left, $A$ is some constant, $k$ is some constant greater than $0$, and $t$ represents time elapsed. Using our given half-life:

$$\frac{1}{2}A=Ae^{-k(5600)}\rightarrow k=-\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{2})}{5600}=\frac{\ln{(2)}}{5600}\approx0.000123776$$

From here, we can plug in our value of $k$ into our original equation:

$$xA=Ae^{-(0.000123776)(7000)}\rightarrow x=.420449$$

or that $42.05\text{%}$ of the $C^{14}$ remains. However, the book gives the answer "between $32$ and $33$ percent," so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if perhaps it's just a typo (i.e. it should be "between $42$ and $43$ percent"). I followed the method that gave me the correct answers for the first two problems, so any suggestions/comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the town existed 7000 bc, which is 9000 years ago

Comment: Derp. Thank you.